# Adding Sticky Footer for Drawer React Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React Material UI and I am trying to add a sticky footer to the drawer component.

Here is the sandbox with the drawer added for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-tree-nfqme?file=/src/App.js

The documentation shows no support either by other components or the Drawer API.

I have tried messing with Containers and using custom CSS styles to make position sticky at bottom but that just broke the html completely

```js
export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

i used display: grid in the same situation.

```js
 export const Container = styled.div`
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateRows: "1fr auto", //or "1fr 100px" if fixed height of footer
    minHeight: "100%",   
`;
```

Where first element inside grid wraper will fit all available space, and footer will be like sticky second element at the bootom of screen.